# How do you archive an entire website for offline viewing?

Tags: html, web-crawler, archive

We actually have burned static/archived copies of our asp.net websites for customers many times.  We have used [WebZip](http://www.spidersoft.com/) until now but we have had endless problems with crashes, downloaded pages not being re-linked correctly, etc.

We basically need an application that crawls and downloads static copies of everything on our asp.net website (pages, images, documents, css, etc) and then processes the downloaded pages so that they can be browsed locally without an internet connection (get rid of absolute urls in links, etc).  The more idiot proof the better.  This seems like a pretty common and (relatively) simple process but I have tried a few other applications and have been really unimpressed

Does anyone have archive software they would recommend?  Does anyone have a really simple process they would share?

Comment: Check out https://archivebox.io, it's an open-source, self-hosted tool that creates a local, static, browsable HTML clone of websites (it saves HTML, JS, media files, PDFs, screenshot, static assets and more).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Windows, you can look at [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/).  It's very configurable allowing you to set the speed of the downloads.  But you can just point it at a website and run it too with no configuration at all.

In my experience it's been a really good tool and works well.  Some of the things I like about HTTrack are:

- Open Source license
- Resumes stopped downloads
- Can update an existing archive
- You can configure it to be non-aggressive when it downloads so it doesn't waste your bandwidth and the bandwidth of the site.

Comment: httrack also exists for linux.

Comment: It also exists for Mac - `brew install httrack`

Answer (score 68):

You could use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/):

```
wget -m -k -K -E http://url/of/web/site
```

Comment: From the --help, I can see what the rest do, but what do the flags K (capital) and E do?

Comment: Don't forget the -p switch to get images and other embedded objects, too. (-E is for converting to html extension. -K is to backup the original file with extension .orig)

Comment: The longer, but less cryptic version: `wget --mirror --convert-links --backup-converted --adjust-extension http://url/of/web/site `

Comment: For me this just gets the index.html

Comment: Yes, for me too, it only retrieves index.html.  And the squarespace site I'm trying to get retrieve locally from keeps giving me error 429 "Too Many Requests". :(  I've event setup rate limiting and wait.

Comment: not working if links are with javascrpts. Javascript wget do not support.

Comment: For me, HTTrack worked a lot better. I archived a really old php page and all img tags pointed to a php file with query params. HTTrack renamed them to .jpg / .png files and adjusted the img tag accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

The [Wayback Machine Downloader](https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader) by [hartator](https://github.com/hartator) is simple and fast.

Install via Ruby, then run with the desired domain and optional timestamp from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/).

```
sudo gem install wayback_machine_downloader
mkdir example
cd example
wayback_machine_downloader http://example.com --timestamp 19700101000000
```

Answer (score 4):

I use [Blue Crab](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/internet_utilities/bluecrab.html) on OSX and [WebCopier](http://www.download.com/WebCopier/3000-2377_4-10028393.html?tag=mncol;pop) on Windows.

Comment: Blue Crab is a pretty damn crashy app today.

Answer (score 2):

wget -r -k

... and investigate the rest of the options. I hope you've followed these guidelines:http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html so all your resources are safe with GET requests.

Answer (score 1):

I just use: `wget -m <url>`.

Comment: This only gets the home page, not the whole site.

Answer (score 1):

For OS X users, I've found the sitesucker application found [here](https://ricks-apps.com/) works well without configuring anything but how deep it follows links.

Comment: sitesucker.us website doesn't load as of Jan 2018.

Comment: works again but changed url to where sitesucker.us was redirecting to the author's development website ricks-apps.com

Answer (score 1):

If your customers are archiving for compliance issues, you want to ensure that the content can be authenticated. The options listed are fine for simple viewing, but they aren't legally admissible. In that case, you're looking for timestamps and digital signatures. Much more complicated if you're doing it yourself. I'd suggest a service such as [PageFreezer](https://www.pagefreezer.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using HTTrack for several years now.  It handles all of the inter-page linking, etc. just fine.  My only complaint is that I haven't found a good way to keep it limited to a sub-site very well.  For instance, if there is a site www.foo.com/steve that I want to archive, it will likely follow links to www.foo.com/rowe and archive that too.  Otherwise it's great.  Highly configurable and reliable.