# Copying the folder from server to the local directory

Tags: c#

I am developing a software for downloading a website in C# but I have some trouble in copying the folder from server to the local directory. I am implementing following code for this purpose;

```
  public static void CopyFilesRecursively(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
  {
      try
      {
          foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in source.GetDirectories())
                CopyFilesRecursively(dir, target.CreateSubdirectory(dir.Name));
          foreach (FileInfo file in source.GetFiles())
                file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, file.Name));
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Form2", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }
  }
```

And the function call is

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    try
    {
         CopyFilesRecursively(new DirectoryInfo(@"https:facebook.com"), new DirectoryInfo(@"G:\Projects\"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Form2", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

The message box shows that "the given path format is not supported."

Comment: `DirectoryInfo` is for a local or network path, not for an https resource.

Comment: Maybe you need a authentication to see an remote path, look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433570/access-a-remote-directory-from-c-sharp

Comment: Rob! what for downloading folder from https resource?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file from a URL in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c)

Comment: Are you want to download a file or a complete web site?

Comment: Rob..this is for downloading a file.....i need help for downloading complete website with its links...a complete website may have different webpages with different extensions...i cannot give a specific extension in code

Answer (score 0):

As we are aware, all the web sites hosted on internet uses *virtual* path's (which are more readable and provide more security) for their files and folders. Actual files and folders are on a server behind those virtual path. So to copy a file or a folder from a remote server we need the actual path of the resource.

I provide following code snippet for downloading a file from a server which deployed by my self (I know the directory structure of it of course)

```
string filename = "MyPage.xml";
string filesource = Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles/") + filename; // server file "MyPage.xml" available in server directory "files"
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(filesource);
string filedest = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()+"MyFile.xml";
fi.CopyTo(filedest);
```

These are some other SO posts you can look for;

[How to download a file from a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c)
[Copy image file from web url to local folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824182/copy-image-file-from-web-url-to-local-folder)
[how to copy contents of a website using a .net desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786151/how-to-copy-contents-of-a-website-using-a-net-desktop-application)
[how to copy all text from a certain webpage and save it to notepad C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118660/how-to-copy-all-text-from-a-certain-webpage-and-save-it-to-notepad-c-sharp)
[How do you archive an entire website for offline viewing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538865/how-do-you-archive-an-entire-website-for-offline-viewing)

Comment: this code is for saving a file...i need code for saving website with different types of file